# Fluent Validation in MVC: specify RuleSet for Client-Side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, fluentvalidation

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 project I have validator for one of my view models, that contain rules definition for RuleSets. `Edit` ruleset used in Post action, when all client validation passed. `Url` and `Email` rule sets rules used in `Edit` ruleset (you can see it below) and in special ajax actions that validate only Email and only Url accordingly.

My problem is that view doesn't know that it should use `Edit` rule set for client html attributes generation, and use `default` rule set, which is empty. **How can I tell view to use `Edit` rule set for input attributes generation?**

Model:

```
public class ShopInfoViewModel
{
    public long ShopId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Validator:

```
public class ShopInfoViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ShopInfoViewModel>
{
    public ShopInfoViewModelValidator()
    {
        var shopManagementService = ServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<IShopService>();

        RuleSet("Edit", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter name.")
                .Length(0, 255).WithMessage("Name length should not exceed 255 chars.");

            RuleFor(x => x.Description)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter name.")
                .Length(0, 10000).WithMessage("Name length should not exceed 10000 chars.");

            ApplyUrlRule(shopManagementService);
            ApplyEmailRule(shopManagementService);
        });

        RuleSet("Url", () => ApplyUrlRule(shopManagementService));
        RuleSet("Email", () => ApplyEmailRule(shopManagementService));
    }

    private void ApplyUrlRule(IShopService shopService)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Url)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter url.")
            .Length(4, 30).WithMessage("Length between 4 and 30 chars.")
            .Matches(@"[a-z\-\d]").WithMessage("Incorrect format.")
            .Must((model, url) => shopService.Available(url, model.ShopId)).WithMessage("Shop with this url already exists.");
    }

    private void ApplyEmailRule(IShopService shopService)
    {
        // similar to url rule: not empty, length, regex and must check for unique
    }
}
```

Validation action example:

```
 public ActionResult ValidateShopInfoUrl([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "Url")]
        ShopInfoViewModel infoViewModel)
 {
     return Validation(ModelState);
 }
```

Get and Post actions for `ShopInfoViewModel`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShopInfo()
{
    var viewModel = OwnedShop.ToViewModel();
    return PartialView("_ShopInfo", viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShopInfo(CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "Edit")]ShopInfoViewModel infoViewModel)
    {
        var success = false;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // save logic goes here
        }
    }
```

View contains next code:

```
@{
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
}
<form class="master-form" action="@Url.RouteUrl(ManagementRoutes.ShopInfo)" method="POST" id="masterforminfo">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Url, new { validationUrl = Url.RouteUrl(ManagementRoutes.ValidateShopInfoUrl) })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { validationUrl = Url.RouteUrl(ManagementRoutes.ValidateShopInfoEmail) })
    <input type="submit" name="asdfasfd" value="Сохранить" style="display: none">
</form>
```

Result html input (without any client validation attributes):

```
<input name="Name" type="text" value="Super Shop"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging in FluentValidation sources I found solution. To tell view that you want to use specific ruleset, decorate your action, that returns view, with `RuleSetForClientSideMessagesAttribute`:

```
[HttpGet]
[RuleSetForClientSideMessages("Edit")]
public ActionResult ShopInfo()
{
    var viewModel = OwnedShop.ToViewModel();
    return PartialView("_ShopInfo", viewModel);
}
```

If you need to specify more than one ruleset — use another constructor overload and separate rulesets with commas:

```
[RuleSetForClientSideMessages("Edit", "Email", "Url")]
public ActionResult ShopInfo()
{
    var viewModel = OwnedShop.ToViewModel();
    return PartialView("_ShopInfo", viewModel);
}
```

If you need to decide about which ruleset would be used directly in action — you can hack FluentValidation by putting array in HttpContext next way (`RuleSetForClientSideMessagesAttribute` currently is not designed to be overriden):

```
public ActionResult ShopInfo(validateOnlyEmail)
{
    var emailRuleSet = new[]{"Email"};
    var allRuleSet = new[]{"Edit", "Url", "Email"};

    var actualRuleSet = validateOnlyEmail ? emailRuleSet : allRuleSet;
    HttpContext.Items["_FV_ClientSideRuleSet"] = actualRuleSet;

    return PartialView("_ShopInfo", viewModel);
}
```

Unfortunately, there are no info about this attribute in official documentation.

**UPDATE**

In newest version we have special extension method for dynamic ruleset setting, that you should use inside your **action method** or inside `OnActionExecuting`/`OnActionExecuted`/`OnResultExecuting` override methods of controller:

```
ControllerContext.SetRulesetForClientsideMessages("Edit", "Email");
```

Or inside custom `ActionFilter`/`ResultFilter`:

```
public class MyFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        ((Controller)context.Controller).ControllerContext.SetRulesetForClientsideMessages("Edit", "Email");
        //same syntax for OnActionExecuted/OnResultExecuting
    }
}
```

Comment: The official documentation is a Wiki. Please add it there yourself.

Comment: One thing of note that tripped me up on a couple of refactorings is that the Items collection should be populated with type `new string[]`, NOT `string`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this as the library has been updated to account for this situation...

As of [7.4.0](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/373), it's possible to dynamically select one or multiple rule sets based on your specific conditions;

```
ControllerContext.SetRulesetForClientsideMessages("ruleset1", "ruleset2" /*...etc*);
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on this can be found in the latest FluentValidation site:
https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#asp-net-mvc-5

Adding the CustomizeValidator attribute to the action will apply the ruleset within the pipeline when the validator is being initialized and the model is being automatically validated.

```
   public ActionResult Save([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet="MyRuleset")] Customer cust) {
   // ...
   }
```