# MVC with Fluent validation when set a rule the view doesn't validate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, fluentvalidation

I include the set rule in the validator for my LoginModel, but when I include this `RuleSet` the view doesn't validate by jQuery Validate.

I use jQuery Validate Unobtrusive.

If I remove the rule the view validate correctly.

The problem is that razor doesn't include the validation rules when I include the property en the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
```

This is the model validator with the `RuleSet`:

```
public class LoginModelValidator : AbstractValidator<LoginModel>
{
    public LoginModelValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("login", () => 
        {
            RuleFor(model => model.Email)
                .NotNull()
                .EmailAddress();

            RuleFor(model => model.Password).NotNull();
        });

        /*
        RuleSet("forgotpass", () => 
        {
            RuleFor(model => model.Email)
                .NotNull()
                .EmailAddress();
        });
        */ 
    }
}
```

When send the request, in the action I include this acording the [documentation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc) in 'Validator customization' section:

```
[CustomizeValidator(RuleSet="login")]
```

for validate the rule `login` and it work find. The problen is in the view.

**edit: validate in controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult>  Login([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet="login")] LoginModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    ...
```

**edit: more information**

I use jquery validate for validate the model. As I described before, if I not included a "ruleset" it work fine.

Comment: can we see how you used it in the controller..?

Comment: @pjobs yes, but the problem is in the view, when it try to validate by jquery validate.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking.  Please edit your question to include all relevant details, including the validation on the view, the call to the controller and the subsequent validation failures in the model.

Comment: I see what you are saying , so you have other fluent validations other than this ruleset, that are not being executed once you include this ruleset validation, am I right?

Comment: @SteveMitcham, yes this is unclear, my English is bad. I rewrote the question to see if this clearer.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say validation _doesn't work_ in the view, you are saying that it is missing, or that it is resulting in something incorrect?

Comment: @pjobs, yes, I need include different validations for different situations

Comment: I know it is very frustrating when some thing is not working as you expect :), can I see your get action method too , so I know how are you applying your clientside ruleset..are you using RuleSetForClientSideMessages ?

Comment: @pjobs I use `CustomizeValidator` as it is in the documentation, but the problem is that razor doesn't include or recognizes the rules when the configuration validation for the model include `RuleSet`

Comment: You may already know it, but just to make sure, validations in Ruleset do not by default propagate to client side unless you use RuleSetForClientSideMessages or you can have validations outside ruleset for clientside validations

Comment: @pjobs yes, this is the solution, can you create the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already know it, but just to make sure, validations in Ruleset do not by default propagate to client side unless you use `RuleSetForClientSideMessages` or you can have validations outside ruleset for clientside validations

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @pjobs answer, if you need to decide about which rule set to use dynamically in action — then you can hack special FluentValidation variable, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29526554/571203).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is usefull for me.