# Fluent Validation, MVC: Triggering Client-Side RuleSet Validation on Button Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation, client-side-validation

### Context

In a view, I've created **one** form for my view model. I've separated the form over multiple sections using the Twitter Bootstrap Wizard plugin. The user can access the next section by clicking a "Next" button. Each section has a Fluent Validation RuleSet defined for the model properties on that section. The rules I've defined in each RuleSet are compatible with Fluent Validaiton's client-side validation.

### Question

Upon clicking the next button, what's the best way:

- To get the validation state for **only** the current section's RuleSet on the **client-side** with Fluent Validation?
- To get Fluent Validation to display client-side validation for only the current section's RuleSet?

### What I've Tried

I've read the [Fluent Validation start guide](https://fluentvalidation.net/start) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908630/fluent-validation-in-mvc-specify-ruleset-for-client-side-validation). While they demonstrate how to achieve what I'm looking for on the server-side, they don't **seem** to address my client-side questions. I bold "seem" because I'm reasonably new to Fluent Validation and MVC, so, I may have misunderstood the links' content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use commands from the jQuery validation library, which Fluent Validation uses.

In an element in your form, define an attribute that will help you recognise a validation group. For example

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.GroupA_TextA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_validation_group = "GroupA" }})
```

Use the `.settings.ignore` syntax from the jQuery validation library to control which groups to validate.

I've made a class that exposes functionality to validate a group in, and the entirety of, a Fluent Validation validated form. I've included the TypeScript and transpiled JavaScript below.

*TypeScript*

```
/**
 * For validating a form when Fluent Validation is used for model valdiation.
 */
interface IFluentValidationFormValidator {
    /**
     * The form to validate.
     */
    form: JQuery<HTMLElement>;

    /**
     * The name of the validation group to validate.
     */
    group: string;

    /**
     * Validate the entire form.
     */
    validate(): boolean;

    /**
     * Validate a validation group in the form.
     * @param group The name of the validation group to validate.
     */
    validateGroup(): boolean;
}

/**
 *
 */
class StandardFluentValidationFormValidator implements IFluentValidationFormValidator {
    /**
     * @inheritdoc 
     */
    form: JQuery<HTMLElement>;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    group: string;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    validate(): boolean {
        const formValidator = this.form.validate();
        formValidator.form();
        return formValidator.valid();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    validateGroup(): boolean {
        // The form validator.
        const formValidator = this.form.validate();

        // Perform standard validation on form if the validation group is undefined.
        if (this.group === undefined) {
            formValidator.form();
            return formValidator.valid();
        }

        // Current group validation settings.
        const initialValidateIgnoreSetting = formValidator.settings.ignore;

        // Ignore all elements but the group.
        formValidator.settings.ignore += `,:not([data-validation-group=${this.group}])`;

        // Valdiate the form.
        formValidator.form();

        // Reset group validation settings.
        formValidator.settings.ignore = initialValidateIgnoreSetting;

        // Return the validation state.
        return formValidator.valid();
    }
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
"use strict";
var StandardFluentValidationFormValidator = (function () {
    function StandardFluentValidationFormValidator() {
    }
    StandardFluentValidationFormValidator.prototype.validate = function () {
        var formValidator = this.form.validate();
        formValidator.form();
        return formValidator.valid();
    };
    StandardFluentValidationFormValidator.prototype.validateGroup = function () {
        var formValidator = this.form.validate();
        if (this.group === undefined) {
            formValidator.form();
            return formValidator.valid();
        }
        var initialValidateIgnoreSetting = formValidator.settings.ignore;
        formValidator.settings.ignore += ",:not([data-validation-group=" + this.group + "])";
        formValidator.form();
        formValidator.settings.ignore = initialValidateIgnoreSetting;
        return formValidator.valid();
    };
    return StandardFluentValidationFormValidator;
}());
```